# OpenSession with WebExtension (pkcs11)

Tags: javascript, mozilla, pkcs#11

I am trying to do Web-extension to Mozilla, which will use pkcs11 to sign, encrypt or verify document, mail.

I am using this api to comunicate with  my eid cards and get slots from them.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pkcs11

Is it somehow possible to OpenSession with this slots in WebExtension plugin?
Because this  pkcs11 seems like have not supported it yet.
I would like to call some function like C_OpenSession and then C_Login.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only purpose of PKCS#11 javascript API in Mozilla nowadays is to register and unregister PKCS#11 libraries available to Firefox. It's even stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pkcs11):

> The `pkcs11` API enables an extension to enumerate PKCS #11 security modules, and to make them accessible to the browser as sources of keys and certificates.

Firefox uses registered PKCS#11 libraries to access client SSL certificates. AFAIK there is no public javascript API that would allow you to call other PKCS#11 functions (such as `C_OpenSession` or `C_Login`) provided by these modules.

There used to be `window.crypto.signText` API available for easy signature creation but [Mozilla killed it in Firefox 33](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/Removing_Proprietary_window.crypto_Functions). They didn't see it as a big deal because PKCS#11 signing could be implemented with extension and they provided [signTextJS extension](https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/) as a proof. Sadly [Mozilla killed it in Firefox 57](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/09/28/webextensions-in-firefox-57/) when they migrated to WebExtensions and removed support for XPCOM-based add-ons.

If you want to use PKCS#11 API from Firefox nowadays then you need to use/create extension which will spawn local process and communicate with it via [native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) or you'll need to use/create application which will spawn local web server and communicate with it via [web requests or web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer.